# Tab Order with CTabCtrl and child CFormViews

Tags: c++, mfc

In my application I have a `CFormView` with a `CTabCtrl`, I also have 4 CFormViews that are children of the main CFormView and that are shown/hidden when the user changes the selected tab.

However, I can't find a way to make the Tab Order to work properly. If the CTabCtrl has the focus, pressing the Tab key has no effect and if one of the child CFormView has the focus the Tab key will move the focus only around the controls inside the CFormView.

I tried changing the z-order of the visible child CFormView to be right after the CTabCtrl with `SetWindowPos`, changed the child CFormViews styles to `WS_EX_CONTROLPARENT` but nothing seems to work.

Comment: I can confirm that CONTROLPARENT does enable tab navigation when the parent Dialog is a CDialog class. Maybe this Just Doesn't Work(TM) if the parent is not a Dialog? I assume you have experimented with the other properties (the wizard will try to give it menus etc?)

Answer (score 1):

You've started out from the wrong implementation: you shouldn't make a `CFormView` with a `CTabCtrl` and then stuff more `CFormView`s into it. This isn't going to work right. Instead, you should work with `CPropertySheet` and `CPropertyPage`, where focus handling has already been taken care of. You will still be able to access the `CTabCtrl` owned by the `CPropertySheet` by calling `GetTabControl()`, but MFC will take care of the problems you've encountered.

Briefly: derive classes from `CPropertySheet` for each of the dialog windows you want to show (e.g., CConfigPage1, CConfigPage2). Create a Dialog resource in the Resource Editor for each of them, and do all of the other standard `CDialog` setup.

Next, derive a class from `CPropertySheet` (e.g., CProps), and (optionally) handle WM_SIZE and TCN_SELCHANGE.

Finally, derive a class from a CView descendent, like `CScrollView` (e.g., CViewMyAwesomeStuff). Then add member variables for the `CPropertySheet` and `CPropertyPage`s, and handle WM_CREATE where you Add() each page to the property sheet and then `Create(this,WS_CHILD|WS_VISIBLE)` the property sheet.

**Bonus**: You can forward the `CView::OnUpdate` to each child `CPropertyPage` by calling `GetPage()` in a loop and calling a function on each of them, or you can send a message to each of them (use a user-defined message, like `WM_APP+1`). They can discover their parent's `CDocument` by calling `GetParent()->GetParent()->GetDocument()`.